# Android List view

Tags: android, imageview, android-listview

While working over `listView` I have came across a trouble situation.

Actually I am having a image view defined in layout that is to be inflated,

And I am doing so by adapter with my own bean class XYZ.

Now what I want is I'm checking the variable pic of the bean.

If no image there ,the image view is to be hidden or gone,

When the "pic" is available it should show the list,

But the `ListView` `getView` is called everytime I scroll,,, The image appear and disappear abruptly on list scroll,

Please help me put of the situation.

I want `ImageView` to be displayed when it is available. And hide it when pic tag is " " (empty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a transparent image and put it in dise the drawable folder
add  a condition in side the getView method 
if (tag==*----*)
ImageView.setImageDrawable(R.Id.TransparentImage)
else
ImageView.setImageDrawable(R.Id.AvailablkeImage)

it is appear like as image is hidden in list view.

I hope this is help.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer,,, Thanks for support. That would certainly work...  I have thought of the same.But actually I am using lazy list as the images take time to load,,, If I put the transparent image in the list . The feel of lazy list will vanish,,, Could it be possible to do without that..     If not I will use the same that u suggest,,,,   And Thanks again for helping me out,,,  With Regards, arpit

Comment: The Image visibility need to be gone in my case... As I do not want to shown blank image space for that....